# How can I update the "count" within my Kotlin app

Tags: kotlin

My app is relatively simple and consists of primarily 3 things: a count, and two buttons to decrement/increment the count. I am unsure if my method of editing the count is out of scope or if the UI needs to be forced to update. Below are the 50 lines of logic.

```
@Composable
fun DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var count = 3 // Int
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.android_robot_svg), contentDescription = "1")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text("Current count: $count")
        Row() {
            Text("Jackson Perry", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Text("(CS 492)")
        }
        Row() {
            Button(onClick = { count = when(count) {
                1 -> 5
                2 -> 1
                3 -> 2
                4 -> 3
                5 -> 4
                else -> 0
            } }) {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.prev))
            }
            Button(onClick = { count = when(count) {
                1 -> 2
                2 -> 3
                3 -> 4
                4 -> 5
                5 -> 1
                else -> 0
            } }) {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.next))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The UI is appearing as intended, yet the buttons seem to have no effect. Here is how it [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyhOM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a variable's change in value stick, you have to `remember` it. To cause the UI to update after a variable is changed, you have to make the variable use State. So, you need to do both. Change

```
var count = 3
```

to

```
var count: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(3) }
```

and it will work. Using `by` instead of `=` makes the State a variable *delegate* so you can directly change its value without having to use `.value` each time.

---

By the way, you should avoid ever using when statements for handling every possible math condition. You're a programmer, so make the computer do the calculations for you!

This code that decrements the count:

```
count = when(count) {
  1 -> 5
  2 -> 1
  3 -> 2
  4 -> 3
  5 -> 4
  else -> 0
}
```

could be

```
count--
if (count == 0) count = 5
```

or, if you're comfortable with the remainder operator it could be:

```
count = ((count + 3) % 5) + 1
```

Like wise the incrementing code could be

```
count++
if (count == 6) count = 1
```

or

```
count = (count % 5) + 1
```

Comment: thank you, i'm still pretty new to Kotlin so I rushed the math condition due to ym assignment already being a tad late